# How to implement a TinyMCE Table Drag Handle?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, tinymce, draggable

In tinyMCE you can use the table plugin to insert tables, and that is fine. Now when it comes to moving the table around in your content, it's a bit more tricky.

The correct way of doing it at the moment is to 'select the whole table' and 'drag it to where you want'.

This is a bit clunky and real-life users are most likely to miss a bit of their table in the selection, and dragging this impartial selection will completely break the table.

The correct solution to this problem is probably to implement a kind of 'handle' on top of the table or something that users could grab/drag/drop to securely move the whole table at once.

Any idea of how to implement such a nice thing?

Comment: From what I've seen so far on the web, we are here in browser territory

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle.net entry?

Answer (score 4):

You should put this functionality in an own plugin and if the draggesture event gets fired you check what the user has grabed. If his selection contains a part of the table you replace the drag content with the full table.

Comment: if you need more specific help don't hesitate to ask